# Issue in using Namespace import in Vite React App, importing * as alias

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, namespaces, vite

I have an IconLibrary of React Components in the Icons Folder. While using plain react I use "Icons" as an alias for all the icons in the library by using the following namespace import :

`import * as Icons from "@/styles/Assets/Icons";`

Currently when I try to do the following in Vite App, I get the error as given in the image

**Code**

```
//namespace import 
import * as Icons from "@/styles/Assets/Icons";


//function to get React Component (Icon)
const getIcon = (item) => {
        const Component = Icons[item];
        console.log(Icons);
        console.log(Component);
        return <Component />;
    };

//function call within main React component

{getIcon("VideosIcon")}
```

**Error:**

Console log for Icons retunr the below:

Object { … }
​
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"

[image: Errors in console]

Tried using the following :

const icons = import.meta.glob("@/styles/Assets/Icons*.jsx");